# Is it mandatory to use JDK for CXF or I can use JRE?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

My application uses DynamicClient to create WS client in runtime, it fails if uses just JRE because CXF requires xjc+compiler+etc and if I use JDK everything is ok. But do I really need to use it? IMHO its better to use just set of dependencies in pom instead of undeclared dependency on runtime environment (I mean JDK).

1. Does CXF distribution has such a dependencies or there is a STRONG argument not to have them?
2. Has anyone set of maven dependencies that can replace dependency on JDK?

Comment: Sorry, I know its too late, but did you find a solution to use DynamicClient with JRE. I am stuck with exactly same problem.

Comment: we ended up with using jdk